# strange error in nested manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Below is an illustration of the problem.

```
 a={1->{{8,9},{8,22}},2->{{8,3,19},{8,14,19}}};
 b={1->{1,2},2->{1,2,3}};
 Manipulate[
 Manipulate[
  Thread[case->(item/. b)],
  {case,item/.a,ControlType->Setter}],
 {item,Keys@a}]
```

If you run the above code, it will show this

[image]

then if you switch to item 2, you got an `Thread` error like this

[image]

The error says, Thread encounters unequal length objects. However, the output of Manipulate is actually right! I don't get it, why there is an intermediate error? How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Since the output is okay, you could use `Off[Thread::tdlen]` as a very, very nasty hack. Lateron, you can reactive these error messages with `On[Thread::tdlen]`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! Indeed, I can also mask it with `Quiet`.  But wait for an explanation and a formal way to get rid of it : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a question of timing.  The code segment `Thread[case -> (item /. b)]` is being updated before the inside `Manipulate`. This can happen, I suppose, because the `Thread[..]` segment is wrapped in `Dynamic[]` and is dependent on the symbols `{case, item, a, b}`.  When `Thread[..]` is updated, `item` has changed, but `case` has not yet been updated.  This causes the mismatch in lengths.

The fix would be to control the dependencies with [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) and/or [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)/[`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refresh.html).  Both of the following eliminate the problem (adjust to suit desired dependencies):

```
Manipulate[
 Manipulate[
  Thread[case -> (item /. b)],
  {case, item /. a, ControlType -> Setter},
  TrackedSymbols :> True],
 {item, Keys@a}]

Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Refresh[
   Manipulate[
    Thread[case -> (item /. b)],
    {case, item /. a, ControlType -> Setter}],
   TrackedSymbols :> {item}],
 {item, Keys@a}]
```

In my opinion I can how this could be considered a bug.  When you have nested dependencies that all require an update, do you update from the bottom up or from the top down?  In this simple example, the top-down approach should be down.

Comment: Hi, Michael E2. Thank you very much! +1 for solving the issue. But I don't quite understand `TrackedSymbols`. For example, in the first example, `TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate`, what does this `Manipulate` refer to? The outer manipulate or inner manipulate? And I don't understand why `Manipulate` can track itself?

Comment: @matheorem `TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate` apparently is now supposed to be `TrackedSymbols :> True`: Both track the symbols in the controls in the `Manipulate`, so they would be the same as `TrackedSymbols :> {case}` in example. I learned the first one in a class when V6 came out.

Comment: Thank you so much